# Using command line arguments to find and replace a word in a file in C

Tags: c, string, file, file-io, console

I have a txt file with some text in it. All I have to do is to find a given word in that file and change it with a new given word. These words and text file name will be supplied at the command prompt with the format `C> findword <old word> <new word> <filename>` where `findword` is executable file. A word will end either at a `'.'`, a `' '` or at a `'\n'`. After a word ends if we have some extra space or newline, we will simply ignore it. I have written the below code for this and opened the file in `r+` mode. I don't want to use a temporary file here. All updates should be done on same file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Improper number of arguments\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[3], "r+");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    char word[25];
    int i, flag = 0, len, k;
    char ch;
    len = strlen(argv[1])+1;//assuming new and old words are of same length
    for(i=0;1;i++)
    {
        word[i] = fgetc(fp);
        if(word[i] == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }

        if((word[i] == ' ' || word[i] == '.' || word[i] == '\n') && (flag == 0))
        {
            word[i] = '\0';
            if(strcmp(argv[1], word) == 0)
            {
                fseek(fp, -(len), SEEK_CUR);//To seek back to the start of the old word
                k = fputs(argv[2], fp);//writing new word n place of old word
            }
            flag = 1;//whenever a word is formed, flag is set to 1

        }
        //Below code is used to check if next charcter is whitespace or alphabet, so that we can start forming a new word
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if(ch == EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
        if((flag == 1) && (ch != ' ' && ch != '\n'))//if ch is whitespace or newline we have to simply ignore it.
        {
            i = -1;//i will get incremented to 0 in next iteration and we can start forming new word
            flag = 0;//signifies we will be forming a new word from next iteration.
        }
        fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Now suppose the text file had a single line written as `This is business.`. When i write command on cmd as `C> findword is zz test.txt` where `is` is the old word which has to be replaced, `zz` is the new word  and `test.txt` is the text file. After this command executes i was expecting the text file to be updated to `This zz business` but to my surprise the text file was rewritten as `This zzubusiness.`. The issue is after updating the word `is`, the space after `is` is also getting updated. In this case it is replaced with character `u`. I tried this code with different words and text files and found that the space after `is` is always getting replaced with the second character of the immediate next word. For ex: here space is getting replaced with `u` which is second character of the word `business`. Now i have already spent a lot of time debugging this code but failed to do so. I know this code is not very efficient but I have intentionally written it just to do some experiments with it. What is the issue with this code ? Is it related to using both `fgetc()` and `fputs()` on the same file? or something else that i am missing ?

Comment: Functionally, other than some compiler warnings that should be heeded, the code successfully found and replaced the target word from `is` to `zz`, yielding a perfectly formed sentence: `This zz business.`.   Is this the _exact_ code that you used when you saw the mis-formed output?

Comment: @ryyker Yes, i have tried again but it is showing same problem. I am currently using VS code with gcc compiler.

Comment: I am using a `C99` compiler, and with zero changes to your posted code, it works without a hitch.  There must be some variation in implementation between library functions, i.e. maybe `fseek()` is different.  Have you tried @user3121023 suggestion?

Comment: @user3121023 Yes after adding this line, code is working properly but what is the relevance of adding this line ??

Comment: perhaps you could try to `fflush(fp);` after `fputs();`. I remember that there could be issues when you read after writing without explicitely fflushing or seeking

Comment: so basically that's exaclty the same as @user3121023's suggestion :-), `fflush(fp);` and `fseek(fp 0, SEEK_CUR);` should be equivalent for regular files opend for writing

Comment: @Ingo Leonhardt Yes its perfectly working after using `fflush(fp)` but as far as i know we use `fflush()` to clear any unwanted characters in buffer before we can again take an input. What exactly are we clearing here ?

Comment: **NO** we don't. `fflush()` invokes Undefined Behaviour on input streams (although there are implementations where it works as you think). `fflush()` is for writing output data that is still in the stdio buffer

Comment: Okay got it but again I am not able to see how it is helping in my particular code ?

Comment: It's a case of 'it's just like it is'. There are implementations and situations where `fflush()` or `fseek()` is required after a write operation before you can continue reading. I know I've read that in some doku quite l long time ago but at the moment I can't find it anymore

Comment: found the doku. See my answer

Comment: @user3121023 - I gathered.  Thanks for clarifying, great observation BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [man fopen](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) (emphasis mine)

> Reads and writes may be intermixed on read/write streams in any order.
> **Note that ANSI C requires that a file positioning function intervene between output and input, unless an input operation encounters
> end-of-file.**  (If this condition is not met, then a read is allowed
> to return the result of writes other than the most recent.)
> **Therefore it is good practice (and indeed sometimes necessary under Linux) to put an fseek(3) or fgetpos(3) operation between write and
> read operations on such a stream.**  This operation may be an apparent
> no-op (as in fseek(..., 0L, SEEK_CUR) called for its synchronizing
> side effect).

That "indeed sometimes necessary" is what you've experienced and why `fseek(fp,0,SEEK_CUR);` or `fflush(fp);` after `fputs()` solve the problem.

Comment: I have been trying to debug this code from 2 days. Thanks a lot  :)

Comment: Hey, one more thing : `If this condition is not met, then a read is allowed to return the result of writes other than the most recent`. what exactly this means ?

Comment: good question. Of course, in an implementation where read and write pointer are different one can imagine that a read operation is expected to return the result of a previous write even without an intermediate seek and maybe if there are several writes that could happen, I don't know. Anyway that doesn't apply to your program as you write only once.